# How to set custom cursor for the form's title bar, system menu icon and minimize, maximize and close buttons?

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl

Is there a Windows API for setting up a custom cursor for the form's title bar, system menu icon and minimize, maximize and close buttons?

I'm having a function for loading and setting cursors for a given control:

```
type

 TFrm_Main = class(TForm)
   ....
 private
  procedure SetCursor_For(AControl: TControl; ACursor_FileName: string;
    Const ACurIndex: Integer);
 ...
 end;
 const
   crOpenCursor = 1;
   crRotateCursor = 2;
   crCursor_Water = 3;

 var
   Frm_Main: TFrm_Main;
 ...
 procedure TFrm_Main.SetCursor_For(AControl: TControl; ACursor_FileName: 
  string; const ACurIndex: Integer);
 begin
   Screen.Cursors[ACurIndex] := Loadcursorfromfile(PWideChar(ACursor_FileName));
   AControl.Cursor := ACurIndex;
 end;
```

And I'm using it this way for the form:

```
SetCursor_For(Frm_Main, 'Cursors\Cursor_Rotate.ani', crRotateCursor);
```

But I'm missing a way to setup cursor for particular form parts like form title bar, system menu icon and minimize, maximize and close buttons. Is there a way to set cursor for these form parts?

Comment: From your public data I can see that you have never voted on any answer and you have never accepted any answer to your questions. Maybe you don't know what I mean, so please see [someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Handle the [**WM_SETCURSOR**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382(v=vs.85).aspx) message and test the message parameter's [**HitTest**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Winapi.Messages.TWMSetCursor.HitTest) field for one of the following hit test code values, and set the cursor by using [**SetCursor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393(v=vs.85).aspx) function returning **True** to the message [**Result**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Winapi.Messages.TWMSetCursor.Result) (Windows API macros **TRUE** and **FALSE** coincidentally match to the Delphi's [**Boolean**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Boolean) type values, so you can only typecast there):

- [**HTCAPTION**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx#HTCAPTION) - Title bar
- [**HTSYSMENU**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx#HTSYSMENU) - System menu icon
- [**HTMINBUTTON**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx#HTMINBUTTON) - Minimize button
- [**HTMAXBUTTON**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx#HTMAXBUTTON) - Maximize button
- [**HTCLOSE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx#HTCLOSE) - Close button

For example:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    procedure WMSetCursor(var Msg: TWMSetCursor); message WM_SETCURSOR;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.WMSetCursor(var Msg: TWMSetCursor);
begin
  case Msg.HitTest of
    HTCAPTION:
    begin
      Msg.Result := LRESULT(True);
      Winapi.Windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crHandPoint]);
    end;
    HTSYSMENU:
    begin
      Msg.Result := LRESULT(True);
      Winapi.Windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crHelp]);
    end;
    HTMINBUTTON:
    begin
      Msg.Result := LRESULT(True);
      Winapi.Windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crUpArrow]);
    end;
    HTMAXBUTTON:
    begin
      Msg.Result := LRESULT(True);
      Winapi.Windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crSizeAll]);
    end;
    HTCLOSE:
    begin
      Msg.Result := LRESULT(True);
      Winapi.Windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crNo]);
    end;
  else
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```